# Bluetooth 4 (Bluetooth Smart) on Mac OS

Tags: macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

What is the best way to start developing OS X application that supports new standard of bluetooth? Any good tutorials or detailed documentation? Unfortunately, I can't find really useful information on the web.
I'm using macbook air with built-in support of bluetooth 4, so I'm not facing any hardware problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of tutorials, especially on the Apple Developer website. See all of the Apple examples here: https://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=CoreBluetooth

Also search Github. iOS / Mac OS should generally be the same. [https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=CoreBluetooth&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CoreBluetooth&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1)